# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in 2-line OpenGL program

Tags: macos, opengl, initialization, segmentation-fault

The following simple program produces an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (segmentation fault) when run, and I don't understand why:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>

int main(void) {
  const GLubyte * strVersion;
  // The next line gives an 'EXEC_BAD_ACCESS'
  strVersion = glGetString (GL_VERSION);
}
```

I'm running in Xcode in OS X 10.6.5, and I'm linking against the OpenGL framework. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create an OpenGL context before you can call gl* functions. There are several ways to do that, for example using GLUT or SDL.

Comment: Dead on. GLEssentials (apple sample code) demos creating either legacy or core profile contexts.

Answer (score -1):

For C Specification to create the variable GLubyte you call it by

```
 const GLubyte* glGetString(GL_VERSION );
```

then you should be able to get the version. by the following

```
 const char *GLVersionString = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
 //Or better yet, use the GL3 way to get the version number
 int OpenGLVersion[2];
 glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &OpenGLVersion[0])
 glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &OpenGLVersion[1])
```

here is more basic information on glGetString:

```
 glGetString returns a pointer to a static string describing some aspect of the current GL connection. name can be one of the following:
 GL_VENDOR
     Returns the company responsible for this GL implementation.
     This name does not change from release to release.             
 GL_RENDERER
     Returns the name of the renderer.
     This name is typically specific to a particular configuration of a hardware platform.
     It does not change from release to release.              
 GL_VERSION
     Returns a version or release number.
 GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION
     Returns a version or release number for the shading language.           
 GL_EXTENSIONS
     Returns a space-separated list of supported extensions to GL.
```